# How to Replace multiple nodes of XML efficiently?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am trying to replace around 500 Nodes in a single go for a single document and i am having 5000+ document in my database.

The code which i am using is related to this SO question i asked previously-
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51998598/how-to-replace-multiple-nodes-of-xml-in-one-go-data-hub-framework)

Any suggestions to make my code efficient ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The in-mem-update library should generally be avoided, especially when making numerous method calls for the same document. Since each method walks the entire node tree and generates a brand new document, it can be slow and expensive if you run against large documents and/or make a bunch of mem:* method calls on those docs.

A better replacement would be Ryan Dew's [XQuery XML Memory Operations library](https://github.com/ryanjdew/XQuery-XML-Memory-Operations), or to use XSLT.

Below is an example of how you could perform this sort of "merge" with XSLT that should perform way better than the in-mem-update methods:

```
declare variable $STAGING := document{
<root>
 <ID>1</ID>
 <value1>India</value1>
 <value2>USA</value2>
 <value3>Russia</value3>
 <value4>Srilanka</value4>
 <value5>Europe</value5>
 <value6>Antartica</value6>
 <value7>Spain</value7>
</root>
};

declare variable $FINAL := document{
<root>
 <ID>1</ID>
 <value1></value1>
 <value2></value2>
 <value3></value3>
 <value4></value4>
 <value5>Europe</value5>
 <value6>Antartica</value6>
</root>
};

declare variable $XSLT := 
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

  <xsl:param name="staging-doc"/>
  <xsl:param name="element-names"/>

  <xsl:variable name="final-doc" select="/"/>

  <xsl:key name="staging-elements" match="root/*[local-name() = $element-names]" use="local-name()"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="root/*[local-name() = $element-names]">
    <!--if there is an element in the staging-elements doc with this name, use it. Otherwise, use the matched element from this doc -->
    <xsl:copy-of select="(key('staging-elements', local-name(.), $staging-doc), .)[1]"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      <!-- also copy any other elements with the specified names from the staging document that were not already in the final -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$staging-doc/root/*[local-name() = $element-names and not(key('staging-elements', local-name(), $final-doc))]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>;

declare variable $PARAMS := map:new((
    map:entry("staging-doc", $STAGING), 
    map:entry("element-names", tokenize(("value1,value2,value3,value4,value7"), ",") )
  ));

xdmp:xslt-eval($XSLT, $FINAL, $PARAMS)
```

Comment: @Mads-- Thank you so much. Will it require `xdmp:document-insert ()` as well ? or it will automatically replace all the documents into DB ?

Comment: Yes, you will need to save the result (use in the section of your code where you are conditionally setting $envelope inside of the if ($boolean) then, instead of using the in-mem functions)

Comment: @Mads-- Thank you so much :) That helps.